# Multiple fa-heart like count increment and decrement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I need to increment the count of a fa-heart value on click and decrement on the second click.

Problem is I have multiple fa-heart in the same page, so unable to increment/decrement on the clicked fa-heart.

Here is my fiddle below

https://jsfiddle.net/mehbub/d9e2qotg/1/

```js
(function() {
  const heart = document.getElementById('heart');
  heart.addEventListener('click', function() {
    heart.classList.toggle('red');
  });
})();

$(document).on('click', ".notliked", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass('notliked');
    $this.addClass('liked')
    $count = $('.likes-count');
    $count.text(function(idx, txt) {
    return (+txt == 0) ? 0 : (+txt - 1);
    heart.classList.toggle('grey');

    });

});

$(document).on('click', ".liked", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass('liked');
    $this.addClass('notliked');
    $count = $('.likes-count');
    $count.text(function(idx, txt) {
            return +txt + 1;
    heart.classList.toggle('red');

    });

});
$count.text(function(idx, txt) {
   // convert text to number and increment by one
   return +txt + 1;
});
```

```css
#heart {
  color: grey;  
  font-size: 20px;
}

#heart.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>
robert stephen</p><i class="fa fa-heart liked heart" id="heart" value="1" ></i>
<span class="likes-count"> 100 </span><br>
<p>
James Camroon</p>
<i class="fa fa-heart liked heart" id="heart" value="1" ></i>
<span class="likes-count"> 101 </span><br>

<p>
John Wick</p>
<i class="fa fa-heart liked heart" id="heart" value="1" ></i>
<span class="likes-count"> 37 </span><br>

<p>
James Bond</p>
<i class="fa fa-heart liked heart" id="heart" value="1" ></i>
<span class="likes-count"> 22 </span><br>

<p>
Avengers</p>
<i class="fa fa-heart liked heart" id="heart" value="1" ></i>
<span class="likes-count"> 90 </span>
```

I need individual click increment/decrement for each fa-heart to color change to red if increment, or grey if the decrement

Thanks

Comment: IDs must be unique to the document. Use a unique id on each heart. Also, in your event handlers, get a reference to the element clicked rather than using a global variable, e.g., using `$(this)`.

Comment: But if I do for dynamic data, I will loop through for loop.. then how can it be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the duplicate id `heart` or just remove it since you've already a class `heart` then attach the click to this common class and toggle the classes `liked/notliked`, you could use those classes as a rules in your CSS so no need for `red/grey` classes, something like :

```js
$(document).on('click', ".heart", function() {
  var count = $(this).next('span');

  $(this).toggleClass('notliked liked');

  if ($(this).hasClass('liked')) {
    count.text(Number(count.text()) + 1);
  } else {
    count.text(Number(count.text()) - 1);
  }
});
```

```css
.heart.notliked {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.heart.liked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>robert stephen</p>
<i class="fa fa-heart liked heart" value="1"></i>
<span class="likes-count"> 100 </span><br>

<p>James Camroon</p>
<i class="fa fa-heart liked heart" value="1"></i>
<span class="likes-count"> 101 </span><br>

<p>John Wick</p>
<i class="fa fa-heart liked heart" value="1"></i>
<span class="likes-count"> 37 </span><br>

<p>James Bond</p>
<i class="fa fa-heart liked heart" value="1"></i>
<span class="likes-count"> 22 </span><br>

<p>Avengers</p>
<i class="fa fa-heart liked heart" value="1"></i>
<span class="likes-count"> 90 </span>
```